# Apache Tomcat URL without app name

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I have deployed a tomcat application and made the necessary configurations to web a server (for eliminating port etc.).

I can access the application following way

`http://www.domain.com/appname/`

But I would like to access the app even when user enters

`http://www.domain.com` (just url, no app name)
`http://domain.com` (just domian name)

I am new to Apache configurations, any pointers, or samples would greatly help.

I thought "proxy pass" would resolve...
Do I need to look for rewriting rules or any other?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by putting an `index.html` file into the `webapps/ROOT` folder containing a normal HTML redirection:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>appname</title>
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=./appname/"></HEAD>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy your application as the ROOT webapp in Tomcat in order to eliminate the prefix you still have. Just unzip your app to the `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT` folder or - if deployed as zipped .war file - just rename your file to `ROOT.war` when putting it into the `webapps` folder. It will then be available without application prefix.

Regarding your domain names with / without "www" part: If you are using Apache in front of Tomcat, then the `mod_rewrite` reference documentation has a [good section describing canonical hostnames](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost).

Answer (score 1):

For those who may need solution, I just added the following to httpd.conf and it is working fine for my issues:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$  
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.%[HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R,NE]  

ProxyPass         /appname  http://localhost:8080/appname  
ProxyPassReverse  /recsconnect  http:...  
ProxyPass / http...  
ProxyPassReverse / http....
```

I forgot earlier adding last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another option worth considering, is the [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). Especially useful if you already know mod_rewrite but don't want to use apache.